# Example of Module Which has exactly one Uniserial submodule

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I am looking for example of finite length module $M$ such that it has exactly one uniserial submodule.

Uniserial module is a module whose submodules are totally ordered by inclusion.

What is observe is if finite length module $M$ has exactly one uniserial submodule that means it must have exactly one simple submodule that is exactly one submodule of length $1$.

I know $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ for prime $p$ will work but I am looking for other example.

Comment: So if $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ means $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$, then I guess we infer that you mean "one *proper* uniserial submodule."

Comment: *exactly one simple submodule that is exactly one submodule of length 1.* A simple submodule always has length $1$, of course... I think you are trying to get at the fact it can't be a part of a longer uniserial submodule.

Comment: Yes so apparently it would be only one simple submodule...You know any example of module which has exactly one simple submodule?